# Android: Stopping MediaPlayer activity of widget during Phone Calls

Tags: android, widget, telephonymanager

I have used the solutions provided in this answer [Stopping & Starting music on incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610464/stopping-starting-music-on-incoming-calls) but can't figure out how to implement it in my code. This is what I did -

```
public class KameWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
MediaPlayer mPlay;
Context mContext;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.main);

    Intent active = new Intent(context, KameWidget.class);
    active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, active, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.IBWidget, actionPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
        final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
        }
    } else {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {

            mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.kamehameha);
            mPlay.start();
            PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state,
                        String incomingNumber) {
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
                            || state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                        mPlay.stop();
                    }
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                }
            };
            TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (mgr != null) {
                mgr.listen(phoneStateListener,
                        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
        } else {
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understood:

- You write a media-player app widget
- user presses a button to make it start play (something)
- Call comes in => the sound pauses

Here's how I would go on about it:

1. You bind a service (`android.app.Service`) that plays your audio track to a button on your widget.
2. The service starts the actual MediaPlayer task.
3. When a call comes in, the task pauses the MediaPlayer.
4. When the call ends, the task may (depends on what you want) resume the MediaPlayer.

1) Inside KameWidget.onUpdate(..), something like:

```
Intent intentPlay = new Intent(context, YourPlaySoundService.class);
PendingIntent piPlay = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intentPlay, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layoutId);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play, piPlay);
...
```

2) The Service:

```
public class YourPlaySoundService extends Service {
  ...
  public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Start the Audio Task
    // Instantiate AudioTask
    AudioTask task = new AudioTask();
    // E.g. get your resource ID from the widget:
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    int resId = extras.getInt(YOUR_RESOURCE_PARAM_KEY);
    task.execute(resId);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }
}
```

3) The Audio Task:

```
public class AudioTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
  private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
  // Telephony-Stuff

  public void resume() {
    if(/* check on correct media player state */) {
      mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
  }
  public void pause() {
    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }
  }
  public void stop() {
    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
      mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    mMediaPlayer = null;
  }

  protected Void doInBackground(Integer ... params) {
    int resId = params[0];
    // get the resources from a context (the service)
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mResources.openRawResourceFd(resId);
    try {   
      mMediaPlayer.reset();
      mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(
          afd.getFileDescriptor(), 
          afd.getStartOffset(),
          afd.getDeclaredLength()
          );
      mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
          mp.seekTo(0);
          mp.start();
        }
      });
      mMediaPlayer.prepare();
      afd.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  // Copied from your link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5610996/747906
  PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            //Not in call: Play music
        } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            //A call is dialing, active or on hold
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
  };
}
```

I don't really know how the telephony stuff works. You'll have to figure it out yourself.

This is my idea. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for uour help. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to implement this in my code. The TelephonyManager class is showing errors and also i don't know what to do with the OnRecieve() and how to use OnStartCommand(). :(

Comment: afaik, you don't need onReceive(). In the phone state listener you would just simply call audioTask.pause() or audioTask.resume().