# MediaPlayer Does not stop when a phone call is received

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, phone-call

MediaPlayer does not pause when a phone call is received. If anyone can help would be great!

Code:

```
 public class player1 extends Activity implements Runnable {


private  MediaPlayer mp;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ImageButton pauseicon;
private final int NUM_SOUND_FILES = 3;  //*****REPLACE THIS WITH THE ACTUAL NUMBER OF SOUND FILES YOU HAVE*****
private int mfile[] = new int[NUM_SOUND_FILES];
private Random rnd = new Random();

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player_1);
        pauseicon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pauseicon);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        mfile[0] = R.raw.sound01;  //****REPLACE THESE WITH THE PROPER NAMES OF YOUR SOUND FILES
        mfile[1] = R.raw.sound02;  //PLACE THE SOUND FILES IN THE /res/raw/ FOLDER IN YOUR PROJECT*****
        mfile[2] = R.raw.sound03;
        // Listeners
        /**
         * Play button click event
         * plays a song and changes button to pause image
         * pauses a song and changes button to play image
         * */


        try{
             mp = MediaPlayer.create(player1.this, mfile[rnd.nextInt(NUM_SOUND_FILES)]);
             mp.seekTo(0);
             mp.start(); ;         
             progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
             progressBar.setProgress(0);
             progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
             new Thread(this).start();

         } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

       PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    mp.pause();
                } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    //Not in call: Play music
                } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    //A call is dialing, active or on hold
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
          };


        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pauseicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
              mp.seekTo(0);

            }
        });

        pauseicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                  if(mp.isPlaying()) {
                     mp.pause();
                     ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.playicon);
                  } else {
                     mp.start();
                     ((ImageButton) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);

                  }

               }
            });
   }
   static boolean runThread = true;
   public void run() {
        while ( runThread )  {
              int currentPosition=0;
              int total = mp.getDuration();
              if ( mp != null && currentPosition <= total )  {
              try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 return;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                 return;
              }            
              progressBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
           } else
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        runThread = false; 
    }



   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);


        if (mp != null)
        if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

       }
    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed(){
      if (mp != null){
          if(mp.isPlaying())
              mp.stop();

          mp.release();
      }

      //there is no reason to call super.finish(); here
      //call super.onBackPressed(); and it will finish that activity for you
      super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
    }
```

New Error

```
 09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.mediaplayer/com.example.mediaplayer.player1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3019)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2997)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1273)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at com.example.mediaplayer.player1.onPause(player1.java:172)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5235)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3050)
09-10 19:41:45.250: E/AndroidRuntime(18428):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610464/stopping-starting-music-on-incoming-calls

Answer (score 11):

You need an `AudioManager` to manage audio focus. Here is a neat explanation of how it works: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html.

Here is a simple example showing how to implement it in your app: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#audiofocus.

> Even though only one activity can run at any given time, Android is a
>   multi-tasking environment. This poses a particular challenge to
>   applications that use audio, because there is only one audio output
>   and there may be several media services competing for its use. Before
>   Android 2.2, there was no built-in mechanism to address this issue,
>   which could in some cases lead to a bad user experience. For example,
>   when a user is listening to music and another application needs to
>   notify the user of something very important, the user might not hear
>   the notification tone due to the loud music. Starting with Android
>   2.2, the platform offers a way for applications to negotiate their use of the device's audio output. This mechanism is called Audio Focus.

Example implementation:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    // could not get audio focus.
}


....
....

public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            // resume playback
            if (mMediaPlayer == null) initMediaPlayer();
            else if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.start();
            mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
            // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
            // is likely to resume
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.pause();
            break;

        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
            // at an attenuated level
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps in this code would be necessary to add in: "case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:" the code: "audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);"? (as says in the url that you have linked: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try add these functions to your activity.

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
  super.onPause();

  if (mp != null){
      if(mp.isPlaying())
          mp.pause();

  }

}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();

if (mp != null){
      if(!mp.isPlaying())
          mp.prepare();
          mp.start();

  }
} 

@Override
public void onStop()
{
super.onStop();

if (mp != null){
      if(mp.isPlaying())
          mp.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but when the phone call is finished and it goes back to the app, it crashes ill post the log in question. Any help?

Comment: I don't know if it will help but try to remove mp.release(); from onStop function.

Comment: @SteveF : If you stop `MediaPlayer` you have to call `prepare()` again before calling `start()`. Instead of calling `mp.stop()` in the `Activity` `onPause()` method, you should call `mp.pause()`.

Comment: Hey, this works but now when you press the back button to go back to the main menu of the app, it crashes ill post the crash

Comment: Any ideas? Ive posted the crash?

Comment: this solution has the collateral that whenever you minimize your player it will stop playing, which is bad user experience. A better approach would be to use the AudioManager option. Another option is to register a receiver and catch the incoming call event and pause your media player. 
    <receiver android:name=".receivers.IncomingCallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Comment: This solution does not work with newer versions of android sdk. onPause is no longer called when receiving a phone call.