# Holding music service during call Android Programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, audio-player, phone-state-listener, android-music-player

I am building a music player and i am able to play music in background through music service. But the problem arises when i receive a call service is still running in background. I want to hold my music service during call.

reference

[Stopping & Starting music on incoming calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610464/stopping-starting-music-on-incoming-calls)

I already try it by creating a receiver but got error

> PhoneReciever.java

```
public class PhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

TelephonyManager telManager;
Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.context=context;

    telManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}

private final PhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: {
                //PAUSE

                break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: {

                break;
            }
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: {
                //PLAY

                break;
            }
            default: { }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
};
}
```

> added in Manifest.xml in

```
 <receiver android:name=".PhoneReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> Logcat:

[image]
please help if you noticed any mistake or any other way to do it.

Comment: Try including the full package name for your PhoneReceiver in the manifest and see if that works.

Comment: Also, can you post some code on how you are instantiating the receiver and where do you register and unregister it?