# Stop app processes on phone call?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, incoming-call

I have an app which plays audio. The thing is, when I get a call on my phone while I am interacting with the app, the audio **continues** to play. This becomes a problem because the audio makes it hard to understand what the person is saying. **Is there any method that gets called when the user is talking on a call?** That way I can mute my audio there. I have thoroughly researched the **activity life cycle**, but cannot find anything that will help me with this issue. I really appreciate all of your expert advice.

I have tried to put this code into my BaseActivity which gets extended by all other activities:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Incoming call: Pause music

                TwentySeconds.stopTimer();
                Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, FinishedBeforeTimer.class);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "INCOMING CALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not in call: Play music
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold

                TwentySeconds.stopTimer();
                Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, FinishedBeforeTimer.class);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "DIALING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**But then the strangest thing happens. When I call the my phone, the phone I am calling with says that I can't call my phone.** I am confused as to what to do now, I really appreciate your time.

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610464/stopping-starting-music-on-incoming-calls

Comment: @johnrao07 I have updated my answer. For some reason, using the code from that page results in not letting me call my phone! Please see the edit. Thanks!

Comment: which class you using to play audio?

Comment: @johnrao07  I am actually playing the audio in a background service

Comment: as what i see, you have'nt implemented the completed code, Try working on the code and  try reading the other links on the page I linked.